# $y' = \frac{y^2-1}{x^2-1}, y(2)=2$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

To solve the IVP: $y' = \frac{y^2-1}{x^2-1}, y(2)=2$.

$y' = \frac{y^2-1}{x^2-1} \implies \frac{dy}{y^2-1} = \frac{dx}{x^2-1} \implies (\frac{1}{y-1} -\frac{1}{y+1})dy = (\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1})dx$

Integrating both sides and applying inital condition we have
$$\ln \frac{|y-1|}{|y+1|} = \ln \frac{|x-1|}{|x+1|} \implies |\frac{y-1}{y+1}| = |\frac{x-1}{x+1}|$$

Is the solution correct? Can we say further?

Comment: Can you simplify it to see that $y = x$ must be the only solution?

Comment: @Rohan i have checked that ... but does x=y satisfies the differential equation??

Comment: Oh yes, we'll then get for $y(x) = x$, $$y' = \frac{x^2 -1}{x^2-1} = 1$$ which is satisfied by the given function. Also, $y(2) = 2$.

Comment: @user8795 Recall that The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is a Ricatti's equation and you found a particular solution $y(x)=x$. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

You, probably, will find a solution such as:

$$ y(x)=\frac{-cx+c-x-1}{cx-c-x-1}$$

Applying $f(2)=2$

$$ \frac{-2c+c-2-1}{2c-c-2-1} = \frac{-c-3}{c-3} = 2 \implies 3c-3=0 \implies c=1$$

thus

$$ y(x)=\frac{-x+1-x-1}{x-1-x-1}=\frac{-2x}{-2}=x$$

Concluding, $y(x)=x$ is the unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the initial condition and that any non-zero sign is locally constant you even get
$$
\frac{y-1}{y+1}=\frac{x-1}{x+1}.
$$
Now cross-multiply and simplify to get $y(x)=x$.

You could also have made the hypothesis $y(x)=x$ from the start because of the symmetry of the problem under reflection on the diagonal. Then confirm that the ODE reduces to $y'(x)=1$, which is also the slope of the hypothesis function. By uniqueness there can be no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

If
$y'
=\dfrac{f(y)}{f(x)}
$
then
$\dfrac{y'}{f(y)}
=\dfrac1{f(x)}
$.
Integrating.
with
$G(x) = \int \dfrac{dx}{f(x)}
$,
$G(y) = G(x)+c
$.

If
$y(x) = x$ for some $x_0$,
then $c = 0$
so
$G(y) = G(x)$.

If $G$ is monotonic,
then
$y(x) = x$.

This problem
is the case
$f(x) = x^2-1$
and $x_0 = 2$,
so that

$\begin{array}\\
G(x)
&=\int \dfrac{dt}{t^2-1}\\
&=\frac12\ln(\frac{1-x}{1+x})
\qquad\text{for } 0 < x < 1\\
&=\frac12\ln(\frac{1-1/x}{1+1/x})
\qquad\text{for } x > 1\\
\end{array}
$

and $G$ is monotonic
in each of the two ranges.

Since $f(1) = 0$,
$G(1)$ is not defined,
so we can not integrate
through $x = 1$.